# Is the negation of on injective and surjective statements

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$f$ is injective and $g$ is surjective, then $g\circ f$ is injective

$f$ is surjective and $g$ is injective, then $g\circ f$ is injective

Are these 2 statements negations of each other?

i.e. If i prove the first statement true, the second is false.

Answer (score 0):

The negation of $P\implies Q$ is $P\text{ and no }Q$. The first does not imply the falsity of the second.

The negation of the first is $$(f\text{ is injective and }g\text{ is surjective})\quad\text{and}\quad g\circ f\text{ is }\textbf{not}\text{ injective}.$$

We can prove the first by counterexample:
Let $f\colon\Bbb R\to[0,+\infty)$ be a function defined by $f(x):=x^2$ (surjective but no injecive), and let $g\colon[0,+\infty)\to\Bbb R$ be a function defined by $g(x):=2x$ (injective, but no surjective).

But $$g\circ f(-2)=8=g\circ f(2).$$ So we have that two different numbers, namely $-2$ and $2$, maps to the same value. Thus $g\circ f$ cannot be injective.

Comment: oh ok. because i'm having such a hard time trying to disprove the second statement. Do you have any hints for me to try?

Comment: Suppose $f\colon\Bbb R\to[0,+\infty$ defined by $f(x):=x^2$ (surjective but no injecive), and $g(x):=2x$ (in particular, injective). ¿Is $g\circ f$ injective? See what happen with $g\circ f(-2)$ and $g\circ f(2)$.

Comment: @Danxe: considering that the statements, as they are, have a universal quantification, when you negate them, you just get an existential quantification, i.e. there are a $f, g$ s.t. $f$ injective, $g$ surjective and $g \circ f$ not injective. Hence, you can come up with a counterexample to prove it (e.g. see what Cristhian Gz wrote while I was writing this comment).

Comment: Exactly! :-) The universal quantifier was implicit.